# Metodo que retorna data/hora Java

Tags: java

Após pesquisar varios posts referentes ao assunto, não encontrei um exemplo onde eu crio uma classe "externa" (que nao seja a main por exemplo) e da main chamo o metodo que me da a hora atualizada automaticamente.

Tenho usado a seguinte forma de recuperar data/hora

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss");
            String sDataHora = sdf.format(new Date());
            jDataHora.setText(sDataHora);
        }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se eu entendi direito mas...

```
public class ClasseUtilitaria {

    public static String horaAtualizada() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    }

}


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(ClasseUtilitaria.horaAtualizada());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(ClasseUtilitaria.horaAtualizada());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(ClasseUtilitaria.horaAtualizada());
    }
```